# embeded phonegap in native ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ios-simulator

ihave a phonegap project that i want to emebed in other native ios application. i have followed this [tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2012/11/15/embed-cordovaphonegap-in-your-native-ios-app/), but in the end the app run in the simulator but could not open the index.html page and i have this message on screen:

```
ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found.
```

i have try to re-add the www folder wich is in same root as viewcontroller.m folder  but no results.
any suggests ?

Comment: The www folder should be in the root of your project

Comment: you mean under the blue bar or the root folder?